# How to handle The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process error

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm trying to move videos having frame height more than 900 to different directory but getting below error, How can I resolve this?

**PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'test.mp4' -> '../test.mp4'**

```
import os
import cv2
import shutil

os.chdir('D:\\folder')
print(os.getcwd())

for count, f in enumerate(os.listdir()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    file_path = str(f_name+f_ext)
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path)
    height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    print(height)
    print(width)
    if (height > 900):
        new_path = '../'+file_path
        shutil.move(file_path, new_path)
        print("end")
```

Comment: It looks to me like the command ```cv2.videoCapture(filepath)``` has opened the file and hasn't closed it.  Not knowing what library cv2 is referencing, can't tell you how to close it, but sure if you look through the docs you can find it.

Comment: file_path is almost certainly **not** what you expect it to be. You remove the extension then add it back but without the intervening '.'. Try printing file_path. I suspect that it will either reference a non-existent file or, more likely, a directory. If you're only interested in files with .mp4 extension I suggest you try *glob*

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that you want to examine all/any mp4 files in D:\folder. If the video height is over 900 you then want to move it to the parent directory of D:\folder - i.e., D:\

Try this:

```
from glob import glob
from cv2 import VideoCapture, CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT
from shutil import move
from os.path import join, basename

SOURCE = 'D:\\folder'
TARGET = 'D:\\'

for mp4 in glob(join(SOURCE, '*.mp4')):
    try:
        if VideoCapture(mp4).get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) > 900:
            move(mp4, join(TARGET, basename(mp4)))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception {e} when processing {mp4}')
```

Comment: Getting error. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement VideoCapture (from versions: none)

Comment: @LearningOnly You will have had that error with your code in the question. Can't be certain but you may need to update your cv2 (opencv-python). Works fine in my environment